# BioPython SeqIO fails with Invalid Alphabet found

Tags: python, genbank, biopython

I am trying to store a GenBank file that could be read by Geneious later.
I found an example how to create the GenBank file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65216225/writing-and-saving-genbank-files-with-biobython-seqio-module)

But now I run into `Alphabet` issues.
I tried all protein classes from the [documentation](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Alphabet.IUPAC.html), but all fail with the same error:

`TypeError: Invalid alphabet found, <class 'Bio.Alphabet.ProteinAlphabet'>.`

I dont know what else to do here? Using `biopython==1.73`

```
    record = SeqRecord.SeqRecord(
        Seq.Seq("MIRQALAVAALLLAGTAQADGLIDN", alphabet=Alphabet.ProteinAlphabet),
        id="FooBar",
    )

    with NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w") as genbank:
        SeqIO.write(record, genbank, "genbank")
        pass
```

Comment: If possible, please show a minimum reproducible chunk of code. The code shown here does not include any library imports, so will not work as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly ...

```
from Bio.Alphabet import generic_protein
from Bio.Seq import Seq
```

then ..

```
myprot = Seq('EXAMPLEPROT', alphabet=generic_protein)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried without setting the alphabet but `Seq` needs that parameter. Let me try another way of importing the `Alphabet`

Comment: Using `generic_alphabet` tells me this: `ValueError: Need a Nucleotide or Protein alphabet`

Comment: I was wrong, `generic_protein` does the trick, not `generic_alphabet`

Comment: Thanks @ElDude done .. many thanks.